# AngularJS json output format

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I have problem with outputting data from JSON file

```
{
"movie": {
    "RowCount": 0,
    "Result": [
        {
            "movieID": "124",
            "moviename": "Hello"
        },
        {
            "movieID": "123",
            "moviename": "World"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I dont know why the {{}} statement wont work with this kind of JSON file. if the JSON File with another format like following

```
{
"discCount": 0,
"results":[
    {
        "disccode": "ABC123"
    },
    {
        "disccode": "ABCD123"
    }
]
}
```

it works perfect just by calling the {{variablename.disccode}}

can anybody help me please? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit, it appeared that you are resolving the wrong property. You should resolve :

```
defer.resolve({
    data: response.movie.Result,         
    rowCount: response.movie.RowCount 
});
```

Then, because the controller stores the data in `$scope.movies`, the following `ng-repeat` will be ok :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="movie in movies">
    <td>{{movie.ID}}</td><td>{{movie.moviename}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: so sir how to edit the function that retrieve the data from JSON file? because currently i am just using $scope.movies      = response.data.. and looks like it is not a correct function, and i dump it in console log, it says undefined

Comment: What do you have in `response` ?

Comment: success(function(response){
                            defer.resolve({
                                            data: response.results,     
                                            albumCount: response.albumCount
                                          });
                        }).

Comment: If you do a `console.log(response)` before the `defer.resolve(..)` what is the output ?

Comment: it says the movie is an object sir, thereafter it displays the result in arrays.
while for the second type of JSON file, it will directly display the results

Comment: If you need help you must provide the structure of the `response` object, or at least `response.results` because that's what you are resolving.

Comment: hello sir I have added codes into the last paragraphs. thanks

Comment: I see that. Please add also the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`. Add this line before the call to `defer.resolve`.

Comment: I already add that line and i can see the all the JSON data sir. what is the difference then?